# como obtener un token a partir de estos datos

Tags: api, swagger

Soy extremadamente nuevo a este tema,  teniendo esta URL :

https://dev.tuten.cl/TutenREST/#!/user/login

Cómo se puede obtener un token?

Espero que me ayuden a entender de qué trata esto, quiero aprender pero es mi primer encuentro con estos temas..

Gracias!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aquí tienen el endpoint de obtención de token:
https://dev.tuten.cl/TutenREST/#!/user/tokenV2

Entiendo que deberás de estar registrado, le pasas los datos oportunos y te responde con el token.

Comment: Necesito usar un programa en específico para pasar los datos? Postman me serviría?

Comment: Swagger es un framework de APIs, para probarlo puedes hacerlo desde ese mismo link. También puedes hacerlo con Postman o cualquier otro.

Comment: Jota, gracias por responder a mi super novata pregunta. Cuando traigo con get, solo recibo un html, dónde puedo registrarme para introducir los datos y obtener el token?

Comment: Pues intuyo que tendrás que registrarte en su propia web: https://dev.tuten.cl/app/usuarios/registro